# Alfresco connected user in Alfresco webscript

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

In a Alfresco webscript I want to get connected user. In share webscript I know there is a root object called `"user"` which allows us to  get  connected user properties.

But in Alfresco webscript this root  object is undefined. Actualy I have to pass connected user's `userName` as argument of the webscript url.

Is there a way to directly get user properties in alfresco webscript (javascript) ?

I'm using alfresco 5.0.d.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alfresco and share webscript has differrent set of javascript api.

You can find that on below link.

Alfresco : http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API

Share : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/APISurf-rootscoped.html

```
person.properties.userName
```

above will return current username in alfresco javascript.